# Bluetooth as beacon and classic simultaneously

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can a Bluetooth device act as a beacon and simultaneously be used for other functions?

I've tried looking around, without finding a concrete answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

A beacon is a Bluetooth Low Energy device that is advertising. The BLE radio is separate from the classic radio, and since the Bluetooth specification does not restrict the operation of classic Bluetooth along side Low Energy functionality then there is no issue performing classic Bluetooth operation while the device is acting as a Beacon.